# explicit specification of variables for stochastic gradient descent

Tags: java, machine-learning

I have a binary classification problem, determine the category associated with a particular document, the documents are rendered as bag-of-words style feature vectors of the form:

Example:

```
Document 1 = ["I", "am", "awesome"]
Document 2 = ["I", "am", "great", "great"]
```

Dictionary is:

```
["I", "am", "awesome", "great"]
```

So the documents as a vector would look like:

```
Document 1 = [1, 1, 1, 0]
Document 2 = [1, 1, 0, 2]
```

I want to apply to this input a stochastic gradient descent algorithm to "minimize the empirical risk involving the [**hinge loss**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss)".

I've searched high and low to see how the stochastic gradient descent algorithm would accept input in this form but I've not found a simple and lucid explaination anywhere.

This is the pseudo code from wikipedia:

```
Choose an initial vector of parameters w and learning rate \alpha.
    Randomly shuffle examples in the training set.
        Repeat until an approximate minimum is obtained:
            For i=1, 2, ..., n, do:
                w := w - alpha DELTA Q_i(w)
```

Would someone please explain to me how the input that I am working with fits into that pseudocode?

I've seen data represented like this:

```
private List<Point2D> loadData() 
{
    List<Point2D> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new Point2D.Double(1, 2));
    data.add(new Point2D.Double(2, 3));
    data.add(new Point2D.Double(3, 4));
    data.add(new Point2D.Double(4, 5));
    data.add(new Point2D.Double(5, 6));
    data.add(new Point2D.Double(6, 7));
    return data;
}
```

also like this:

```
 static double[] x = {2, 4, 6, 8};
 static double[] y = {2, 5, 5, 8};
```

I guess the later is more ameanable to my situation.

This is a perceptron implementation which I'd like to modify to yield a stochastic gradient descent, perhaps someone might be able to point out where I need to make those changes, and how?

```
public static void perceptron(Set<String> globoDict,
   Map<String, int[]> trainingPerceptronInput,
   Map<String, int[]> testPerceptronInput)
{
    //store weights to be averaged. 
   Map<Integer,double[]> cached_weights = new HashMap<Integer,double[]>();


   final int globoDictSize = globoDict.size(); // number of features

   // weights total 32 (31 for input variables and one for bias)
   double[] weights = new double[globoDictSize + 1];
   for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) 
   {
       weights[i] = 0.0;
   }


   int inputSize = trainingPerceptronInput.size();
   double[] outputs = new double[inputSize];
   final double[][] a = Prcptrn_InitOutpt.initializeOutput(trainingPerceptronInput, globoDictSize, outputs, LABEL);


   double globalError;
   int iteration = 0;
   do 
   {
       iteration++;
       globalError = 0;
       // loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
       for (int p = 0; p < inputSize; p++) 
       {
           // calculate predicted class
           double output = Prcptrn_CalcOutpt.calculateOutput(THETA, weights, a, p);
           // difference between predicted and actual class values
           //always either zero or one
           double localError = outputs[p] - output;

           int i;
           for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
           {
               weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a[i][p];
           }
           weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError;

           // summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
           globalError += localError * localError;
       }

       //store weights for averaging
       cached_weights.put( iteration , weights );

       /* Root Mean Squared Error */
       System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt(globalError / inputSize));
   } 
   while (globalError != 0 && iteration <= MAX_ITER);



   int size = globoDictSize + 1;
   //compute averages
   double[] sums = new double[size];
   double[] averages = new double[size];

   for (Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : cached_weights.entrySet()) 
   {
       double[] value = entry.getValue();
       for(int pos=0; pos < size; pos++){
           sums[ pos ] +=  value[ pos ]; 
       }
   }
   for(int pos=0; pos < size; pos++){
       averages[ pos ] = sums[ pos ] / cached_weights.size(); 
   }


   System.out.println("\n=======\nDecision boundary equation:");
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
   {
       System.out.print(" a");
       if (i < 10) System.out.print(0);
       System.out.println( i + " * " + weights[i] + " + " );


   }
   System.out.println(" bias: " + weights[i]);


   //TEST
   //this works because, at this point the weights have already been learned. 
   inputSize = testPerceptronInput.size();
   outputs = new double[inputSize];
   double[][] z = Prcptrn_InitOutpt.initializeOutput(testPerceptronInput, globoDictSize, outputs, LABEL); 

   test_output = Prcptrn_CalcOutpt.calculateOutput(THETA, weights, z, TEST_CLASS);       

   System.out.println("class = " + test_output);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an expression using the weights multiplied by your data representation plugged into the loss function you have chosen. This is how you write Q.
It is in this expression that you use your data. I see nothing wrong with the way you're representing it since after you initialize the w's you will be adjusting them in order to compute a nice decision function.

Comment: I've recently implemented the perceptron algorithm on the same vectors, what you're describing sounds very similar, it seems like it's just a small modification to change that code into gradient descent, is that right?

Comment: Yes, the perceptron uses a threshold and the gradient descent depends upon minimizing a continuous loss function.

Comment: I have notions of what your talking about but would you help clarify your idea for me, possibly by just very quickly and sketchily pseudocodeifying what you mean onto that perceptron function that I added as an edit?